# Type and reference errors javascript on server refresh

Tags: javascript, console, requirejs

I am using `Require js`, when I do **Ctrl+F5 (a server refresh)** I see these errors in my console and script stops working. But when I do a normal refresh, every thing works fine. [image]

Here is how I ahve included scripts in my `main.js`

```
require.config({
baseUrl: '/scripts/',
paths: {
    jquery: 'jquery',
    mousewheel: 'mousewheel',
    jscrollpane: 'jscrollpane',
    jplayer: 'jplayer',
    validate: 'jquery.validate',
    "jquery-ui": 'jquery-ui',
    croppic: 'croppic',
    iframe_transport: 'jquery.iframe-transport',
    fileupload: 'jquery.fileupload',
    //banner: 'jquery.wallform'

}
});
```

Comment: Hi, have you import jQuery before your script ? because `$ is not definied` looks like jQuery is not imported

Comment: I don't have to. I am importing it via `require`

Comment: Hi, there is not enough information. For some scripts you must to specify dependencies manually. Via shim: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim